# d3js drag svg:g item move before drag

Tags: svg, d3.js, drag

I follow the tutorial on dragging group of item here https://gist.github.com/enjalot/1378144

This is what i have http://jsfiddle.net/EwGPu/

```
var circle = svg.append('svg:g').selectAll('circle')
            .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id; });

var g = circle.enter().append('svg:g').call(drag);

g.append('svg:circle').attr('class', 'node')
  .attr('cx', function (d) { return d.x; })
  .attr('cy', function (d) { return d.y; })
  .attr('r', 30)
  .style('fill', function(d) { return d3.rgb(colors(d.id)).brighter().toString(); })
  .style('stroke', function(d) { return d3.rgb(colors(d.id)).darker().toString(); });

g.append('svg:text')
  .attr('x', function (d) { return d.x + 0; })
  .attr('y', function (d) { return d.y + 4; })
  .attr('class', 'id')
  .text(function(d) { return d.id; });

var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on('drag', function (d,i) {
        d.x += d3.event.dx;
        d.y += d3.event.dy;
        d3.select(this).attr("transform", function (d, i) {
            return "translate(" + [d.x,d.y] + ")";
        })
    });
```

However when I try to drag an item, the very first drag move the item way off its current coordinate, but then later on everything is dragged normally. I can't figure why the odd behavior on the very first drag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're using two ways of setting coordinates -- the `transform` attribute for the group and the `cx` and `cy` attributes for the circles. Without any dragging, the position is solely determined by the latter. On drag, you're setting the translation of the group, which takes effect *on top of* the other attributes. That is, you're translating the group which was at (0,0) before to the current position of the circle, causing a jump in coordinates as the `cx` `cy` position remains the same.

It'll save you some headaches later if you use only one of the methods. I've modified your jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/EwGPu/1/) to use only `transform`. This way, dragging works as expected without any jumps. Furthermore, you only need to specify the relative offset of the text instead of the absolute one.

Comment: Perfect explanation. Thank you.